# Python - Accessing imported module from file above

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sure I am doing something embarrassing and daft, but is it possible to access the imported modules in one.py from the function in two.py (the files are in the same directory)?

one.py

```
import requests
import two
print(two.get_google())
```

two.py

```
def get_google():
   return requests.get('http://google.com')
```

Error i get...

```
python3 one.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "one.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(two.get_google())
  File "/myfolder/two.py", line 2, in get_google
    return requests.get('http://google.com')
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Thanks and apologies in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import statements bind a name *within the importing module's namespace*. You must put the `requests` import directly into the module that needs to use this name:

```
# one.py
import two

print(two.get_google())
```

^ removed from `one`, where it was unused, and added to `two`:

```
# two.py
import requests

def get_google():
   return requests.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: Can't test at the moment but if the namespaces are separate does it mean you could have two `requests` without conflict?? It's not something that occurred to me to do but this makes it seem possible.

Comment: That is not possible because of the way the import system works.  If the name `requests` is already present in `sys.modules` it won't be imported again.

Comment: Yeah, that's the bit that's throwing me because, if it's able to make that check between modules, I couldn't see the technical reason that it also wouldn't resolve `requests` to a name. Presumably the root of each check is separated. So `requests` is explicitly bound to `two` when imported into `one`

Comment: Projects that want to control a version use extra namespacing. One such example is `pip`, which vendors requests under `pip._vendor.requests`. This comment should not be taken as an endorsement of vendoring (I generally consider it an anti-pattern).

Answer (score 3):

*(Just so we're clear, consider wim's approach first (and second, third, ...))*

This seems like a weird approach, but if you know this is something you need you ***could*** pass the module loaded in one.py as an argument to your function in two.py:

one.py

```
import requests
import two
print(two.get_google(requests))
```

two.py

```
def get_google(requests):
   return requests.get('http://google.com')
```

But I've only seen a handful of cases where this needed to be done or was helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for the all the info guys, most appreciated!

Comment: Such an approach might more typically be used when passing a `requests.Session` instance.  Passing the requests *module* itself would seem pretty strange to me.